# How to fetch varibles after the workflow execution completes in camunda?

Tags: workflow, camunda, camunda-modeler

I am trying to get variables set during the workflow execution after it completes.

Instantiating workflow in WorkflowStart class and then fetching values

```
ProcessInstance pi = runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByKey("workflowName");
System.out.println("runtimeService.getVariables(getId()) "+runtimeService.getVariables(pi.getId()));
```

the above commands starts workflow, and perform all the executions. So when i write

```
 public class FlowDelegate  implements JavaDelegate {
    public void execute(DelegateExecution execution) throws Exception {
        execution.setVariable("abc123", "123");
        System.out.println("Execution variables - "+execution.getVariables());      
 }
}
```

the above line prints

```
{
  abc123 => Value '123' of type 'PrimitiveValueType[string]'
}
```

So after processInstance executes workflow and tries to access variables i get this stack trace

and executes

```
 System.out.println("runtimeService.getVariables(getId()) "+runtimeService.getVariables(pi.getId()));


ENGINE-16004 Exception while closing command context: execution e575eb8b-7b84-11e8-a237-54e1ad4a38ce doesn't exist: execution is null
 org.camunda.bpm.engine.exception.NullValueException: execution e575eb8b-7b84-11e8-a237-54e1ad4a38ce doesn't exist: execution is null
```

Answer (score 2):

Once the process finished, it is no longer accessible through the runtime api.
You can use. HistoryService#createHistoricVariableInstanceQuery to Access the values.

**Update**: Meanwhile camunda supports return values for the process start, you can use [RuntimeService.html#createProcessInstanceById](https://docs.camunda.org/javadoc/camunda-bpm-platform/7.12/org/camunda/bpm/engine/RuntimeService.html#createProcessInstanceById-java.lang.String-) and then [executeWithVariablesInReturn()](https://docs.camunda.org/javadoc/camunda-bpm-platform/7.12/org/camunda/bpm/engine/runtime/ProcessInstantiationBuilder.html#executeWithVariablesInReturn--) to immediately get the variables of the started instance, without the need for an additional (expensive) query on historic variables.